# Assigning probability for sample() within tapply()

Tags: r, sample, tapply

Using the following:

```
name<-c(rep("Adam", times = 6), rep("Barry", times = 4), rep("Charlie", times = 5))
group<-c(1:15)
probs<-c(0.4, 0.2, 0.1, 0.15, 0.1, 0.05, 0.25, 0.35, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.15, 0.30, 0.15, 0.2)
df<-data.frame(name, group, probs)
```

I am trying to create an output that takes each $name and assigns it a $group based on the probabilities from $probs. For example, Adam has a 40% chance of being in group 1, 20% chance of being in group 2, 10% chance of being in group 3, etc.

The final result would return one group for each name based on those probabilities and would look something like this

```
   Adam   Barry Charlie 
      5      10      12
```

I believe that I should be using tapply() and have run the following, but this does not account for the various probabilities

```
tapply(df$group, df$name, sample, 1)
```

In order to utilize the various probabilities, I have also tried the following, but it returns an error due to an incorrect number of probabilities

```
tapply(df$group, df$name, sample, 1, prob = df$probs)
```

Any insight on how to fix these issue and get the desired output is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not a `tapply()` solution, but here's one with `sample_n()` from `dplyr`.

Renaming your `probs` column as `expected_probs`:

```
name<-c(rep("Adam", times = 6), rep("Barry", times = 4), rep("Charlie", times = 5))
group<-c(1:15)
expected_probs<-c(0.4, 0.2, 0.1, 0.15, 0.1, 0.05, 0.25, 0.35, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.15, 0.30, 0.15, 0.2)
df<-data.frame(name, group, expected_probs)
```

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  sample_n(size = 1, weight = expected_probs)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   name [3]
  name    group expected_probs
  <fct>   <int>          <dbl>
1 Adam        4           0.15
2 Barry       9           0.3 
3 Charlie    12           0.15
```

Checking if the observed results match the expected probabilities by replicating the sample:

```
iterations <- 10000

results <- replicate(expr = df %>% 
                       group_by(name) %>%
                       sample_n(size = 1, weight = expected_probs),
                     n = iterations,
                     simplify = FALSE) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "iteration") %>% 
  group_by(name, group, expected_probs) %>% 
  summarize(observed_probs = n() / iterations)

results

# A tibble: 15 x 4
# Groups:   name, group [15]
   name    group expected_probs observed_probs
   <fct>   <int>          <dbl>          <dbl>
 1 Adam        1           0.4          0.391 
 2 Adam        2           0.2          0.198 
 3 Adam        3           0.1          0.102 
 4 Adam        4           0.15         0.154 
 5 Adam        5           0.1          0.104 
 6 Adam        6           0.05         0.0504
 7 Barry       7           0.25         0.252 
 8 Barry       8           0.35         0.346 
 9 Barry       9           0.3          0.297 
10 Barry      10           0.1          0.105 
11 Charlie    11           0.2          0.202 
12 Charlie    12           0.15         0.151 
13 Charlie    13           0.3          0.294 
14 Charlie    14           0.15         0.153 
15 Charlie    15           0.2          0.201
```

Answer (score 0):

tapply can only take in a vector, so you need to do something like by:

```
by(df,df$name,function(i)sample(i$group,1,prob=i$probs))
```

however the output is not so great,

```
df$name: Adam
[1] 2
------------------------------------------------------------ 
df$name: Barry
[1] 8
------------------------------------------------------------ 
df$name: Charlie
[1] 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution that does not use `tapply`, but does use `split` and `sapply`. We will draw the sample twice. Using set.seed(42) guarantees that you get the same results here. You do not need to use it when you run your own data:

```
set.seed(42)
grps <- split(df, df$name)
sapply(grps, function(x) sample(x$group, 1, prob=x$expected_probs))
#    Adam   Barry Charlie 
#       5      10      13 
# sapply(grps, function(x) sample(x$group, 1, prob=x$expected_probs))
#    Adam   Barry Charlie 
#      3       9      11
```